# Angular does not update View (redux, ionic ...)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-redux, supertab

I have a very simple Ionic page. This page shows a status of a Reduxstate.In this page, I have a button in which I get into another page and there I can change the state and return back.
If I return back the view will not update. I've spent quite a long time researching why that does not work. Unfortunately, no success.

**Component**

```
export class AssetDetailTechnicPage {
    @select(['asset', 'asset'])
    asset$: Observable<Asset>;
}
```

**Template**

```
<ion-content *ngIf="asset$ | async as asset">
    <!--Leistung für Systemeinheit-->
    <ion-card *ngIf="asset.assetSubKind.assetKindId === 2 && (asset.totalMemory || asset.hardDiskCapacity || asset.hardDiskTyp || asset.opticalDriveType
    || asset.bios || asset.displaySize || asset.cpu || asset.gpu)">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-icon name="build"></ion-icon> {{'PERFORMANCE' | translate}}
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-label color="primary" *ngIf="asset.totalMemory">
                {{'MAIN_MEMORY' | translate}}:
            </ion-label> {{asset.totalMemory}}
            <ion-label color="primary" *ngIf="asset.hardDiskCapacity">
                {{'HDD_CAPACITY' | translate}}:
            </ion-label> {{asset.hardDiskCapacity}}
            <ion-label color="primary" *ngIf="asset.hardDiskTyp">
                {{'HDD_TYPE' | translate}}:
            </ion-label> {{asset.hardDiskTyp}}
            <ion-label color="primary" *ngIf="asset.opticalDriveType">


            {{'OPTICAL_DRIVE' | translate}}:
                </ion-label> {{asset.opticalDriveType}}
...... something similar goes on
```

**Try to find out:**

- The page is in an Ionic super-tab Component. I first thought that has something to do with the plugin ionic super-tabs. I took it out and it did not helps
- Maybe it has something to do with redux? Maybe the status does not change? Maybe that does not happen in the Angular Zone? That's why I rewrote it all a bit

  ```
  @select(['asset', 'asset'])
  asset$: Observable<Asset>;
  asset: Asset;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
      this.asset$.subscribe(asset => {
          this.asset = asset;
          console.log(NgZone.isInAngularZone());
      });
  }

  editAsset() {
      this.navCtrl.push(CreateAssetPage, {
          edit: true
      });
  }
  ```

  All changes are accepted and stored in the component. The console output is always true (always in the Angular zone). Why is the view not updated?
- Last time I tried to trigger the changeDetection manually, but this
  led to an error.

  ```
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,  private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      this.asset$.subscribe(asset => {
          this.asset = asset;
          console.log(NgZone.isInAngularZone());
          if(this.asset) {
              this.changeRef.detectChanges();
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take the if Statement out of the content everything works ... Whatever

```
<ng-container *ngIf="asset$ | async as asset">
    <ion-content>
      ....
```